# Magento 1.9: Newbie trying to create a module that triggers a method when a cms page is saved

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to create a very basic module which will trigger the `saveCmsPageObserve()` method when a page in the CMS is saved.  I've tried getting the code to die or write to the log but I didn't have any luck with that.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Magento 1.9 and I've been trying to use these tutorials:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/
http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105

Here's what my code is looking like:

/app/etc/modules/Wyoming_Recruitment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wyoming_Recruitment>

            <!-- Whether our module is active: true or false -->
            <active>true</active>

            <!-- Which code pool to use: core, community or local -->
            <codePool>local</codePool>

        </Wyoming_Recruitment>
    </modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Wyoming/Recruitment/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wyoming_Recruitment>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Wyoming_Recruitment>
    </modules>

    <!-- Configure our module's behavior in the global scope -->
    <global>

        <!-- Defining models -->
        <models>

            <!--
                Unique identifier in the model's node.
                By convention, we put the module's name in lowercase.
            -->

            <wyoming_savecmspageobserve>

                <!--
                    The path to our models directory, with directory
                    separators replaced by underscores
                -->
                <class>Wyoming_Recruitment_Model_Observer</class>

            </wyoming_savecmspageobserve>

        </models>


        <strong>
            <events>
                <cms_page_prepare_save>
                    <observers>
                        <Wyoming_Recruitment_Model_Observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>wyoming_savecmspageobserve/observer</class>
                            <method>saveCmsPageObserve</method>
                        </Wyoming_Recruitment_Model_Observer>
                    </observers>
                </cms_page_prepare_save>
            </events>
        </strong>

    </global>

</config>
```

/app/code/local/Wyoming/Recruitment/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Wyoming_Recruitment_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
   public function __construct()
   {
   }
   public function saveCmsPageObserve($observer)
   {
         $event = $observer->getEvent();
         $model = $event->getPage();
     //print_r($model->getData());
     //    die('test');

      Mage::log("saveCmsPageObserve called", null, 'product-updates.log');


 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure why you have <strong> tags in your XML.  Try removing them first and replace with <adminhtml> :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/app/code/local/Wyoming/Recruitment/etc/config.xml`: file should be

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wyoming_Recruitment>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Wyoming_Recruitment>
    </modules>

    <!-- Configure our module's behavior in the global scope -->
     <adminhtml>     
        <events>
            <cms_page_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <Wyoming_Recruitment_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Wyoming_Recruitment_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveCmsPageObserve</method>
                    </Wyoming_Recruitment_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </cms_page_prepare_save>
        </events>

  </adminhtml> 

</config>
```